# Continuity of 'partial integral'

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Suppose $f:[a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Then is the function $F:[a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x,y)=\int_{x_0}^{x} f(u,y) du$ also continuous, where $x_0 \in [a_1,b_1]$?

Intuitively it seems to be true since integrating a function makes it 'smoother', and the integral of a one dimensional continuous function is continuous (differentiable even), but I'm wondering if anything pathological can happen when the function domain is 2 (or higher) dimensions?

Proof attempt:

To show continuity of $F(x,y)$ at $(x,y)$, intuitively we require $|F(x+h_1,y+h_2)-F(x,y)|$ to be small when $||h||=||(h_1,h_2)||$ is small.

$F(x+h_1,y+h_2)-F(x,y)=\int_{x_0}^{x+h_1} f(u,y+h_2) du-\int_{x_0}^{x} f(u,y) du$

split $\int_{x_0}^{x+h_1} f(u,y+h_2) du$ into $\int_{x_0}^{x} f(u,y+h_2) du+\int_{x}^{x+h_1} f(u,y+h_2) du$ gives:

$F(x+h_1,y+h_2)-F(x,y)=\int_{x_0}^{x} f(u,y+h_2) du-\int_{x_0}^{x} f(u,y) du+\int_{x}^{x+h_1} f(u,y+h_2) du$

Now suppose for all $\frac{\epsilon}{2(b_1-a_1)}>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in [a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2]$,  $||(x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)||<\delta$ implies $|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(b_1-a_1)}$ (note this is assuming uniform continuity of $f$, but since we have $f$ continuous and the domain $[a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2]$ is compact this is ok).

Let the maximum of $f$ in $[a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2]$ be M (exists by continuity over a compact set), then choose $||h||=||(h_1,h_2)||<min(\delta,\frac{\epsilon}{2M})$, then

|$\int_{x_0}^{x} f(u,y+h_2) du-\int_{x_0}^{x} f(u,y) du|\leq\int_{x_0}^{x} |f(u,y+h_2) -f(u,y) |du<(x-x_0)\frac{\epsilon}{2(b_1-a_1)}\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}$
and

$|\int_{x}^{x+h_1} f(u,y+h_2) du|<M\frac{\epsilon}{2M}=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

So $|F(x+h_1,y+h_2)-F(x,y)|\leq|\int_{x_0}^{x} f(u,y+h_2) du-\int_{x_0}^{x} f(u,y) du|+|\int_{x}^{x+h_1} f(u,y+h_2) du| < \epsilon$

Does this look right?

Comment: Yes that's nicely-done! (Strictly, in the third-to-last line it's implicitly assumed $x_0\leq x$, but that's easily fixed with a couple of absolute value signs.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you for verifying!